# Rademacher complexity of k-fold maxima of hyperplanes

Tags: pr.probability

Aryeh Kontorovich wrote a technical report on 'Rademacher complexity of k-fold maxima of hyperplanes.' But its link ([https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~karyeh/rademacher-max-hyperplane.pdf](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Ekaryeh/rademacher-max-hyperplane.pdf)) is not accessible anymore from US. I know there is another paper which generalizes this result: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.06468.pdf but I am trying to see what were the bounds Aryeh Kontorovich got for max function specifically.

Comment: Next time, just write to me! :)

I'm surprised (and somewhat concerned) that the link doesn't work; will look into it. Here's a link that should:

http://ge.tt/4e6EPeA3

Please let me know if you're able to download the pdf.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to download it.  :)

Comment: @Aryeh The link on your website is also working now.